# Can I put the 'query' part of a =QUERY in a cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am playing with Google Spreadsheet's `=QUERY()`, and I was wondering if / how I can put the query part in a cell. For, for example, I have

```
=QUERY(dataset, B1, 1)
```

in cell `A1`, and

```
SELECT *
```

in cell `B1`.

When I try it, I get a `#REF!` error in cell `A1`. If I change the query string though, I get a `#VALUE` error, so it does do something, but not what I expect.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps try:

```
=QUERY(dataset; B1; 1)
```

[image: 0]